# how to prevent cell reuse of uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I use **UICollectionView** and refer to [this link](https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout) implement `scroll table view Fixed single column and row` like below image.

[image: scroll table]

but when I want to add `shadow` property, it display messy.

[image: messy]

I think the reason is that I reuse `cell` when render visual view, but I don't know how to fix it :(

---

provide my code below, thanks for your time!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON


@objc(RNCollection)
class RNCollection : UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  var contentCellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
  var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  static var dataSource = []
  static var sections = 0
  static var rows = 0

  override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: RNCollectionLayout())

    self.registerClass(RNCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier)
    self.directionalLockEnabled = false
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    self.frame = frame
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func setConfig(config: String!) {
    var json: JSON = nil;
    if let data = config.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
      json = JSON(data: data);
    };

    RNCollection.dataSource = json["dataSource"].arrayObject!
    RNCollection.sections = json["sections"].intValue
    RNCollection.rows = json["rows"].intValue
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let contentCell: RNCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(contentCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RNCollectionCell

    contentCell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 232/255.0, green: 232/255.0, blue: 232/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

      if indexPath.row == 0 {
        contentCell.textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
        contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[0] as! NSArray)[0] as? String
      } else {
        contentCell.textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[0] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as? String
      }
    } else {
      contentCell.textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
      contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

      if(indexPath.section % 2 == 0) {
        contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 234/255.0, green: 234/255.0, blue: 236/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
      }

      if indexPath.row == 0 {
        contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[0] as? String
        contentCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        contentCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        contentCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
      } else {
        contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as? String
      }
    }

    return contentCell
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return RNCollection.rows
  }

  // MARK - UICollectionViewDataSource
  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return RNCollection.sections
  }

}
```

Comment: You "don't" prevent reuse. You use the reuse. Try to use a custom cell, and in `prepareForReuse()` method, remove the shadows.

Comment: I agree with @Larme, preventing cell reuse in a collection view of your nature is a terrible idea that will bring serious performance issues to your app.

Comment: @Larme
I think you are right, I'll consider it :)

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying your customizations for a certain section/row and in your else condition you just set the text. You should specify your required/default customization in your else condition. Consider this part of your code

```
  if indexPath.row == 0 {
    contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[0] as? String
    contentCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    contentCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    contentCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
  } else {
    contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as? String
  }
```

You have specified your `shadowOffset`,`shadowOpacity` and `shadowRadius` in your if condition, but you ignored them in your else condition. If you specify the appearance in the else condition you won't have the problem you are facing now. It should look something like this

```
  if indexPath.row == 0 {
    contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[0] as? String
    contentCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    contentCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    contentCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
  } else {
    contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as? String
contentCell.layer.shadowOffset = 0
    contentCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
    contentCell.layer.shadowRadius = 0
  }
```

If you reset everything properly in all your condition checks, this problem won't occur.

Answer (score 2):

You set up shadow when your row is equal to 0:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {...}
```

but if the row is not equal to zero collection view can reuse the cell when the shadow was already set. The solution is reset the shadow when row is not 0, in your code you can do something like this (see todo):

```
    if indexPath.row == 0 { // Set up shadow here
        contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[0] as? String
        contentCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        contentCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        contentCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
      } else {
        contentCell.textLabel.text = (RNCollection.dataSource[indexPath.section] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as? String
        //TODO: Remove the shadow here
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna save the cell setting everytime when your cell appears,you should set every possible condition of the method  "func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell".Do not prevent the reuse of collectionView only if your data or items is few.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, but in Swift, the logic should be the same and not that hard to translate.

In `RNCollectionCell`.

```
//These enums may have a better nam, I agree
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    RNCollectionCellStyleColumnTitle,
    RNCollectionCellStyleColumnValue,
    RNCollectionCellStyleRowTitle,
    RNCollectionCellStyleUpperLeftCorner,
} RNCollectionCellStyle;

-(void)titleIt:(NSString *)title forStyle:(RNCollectionCellStyle)style forSection:(NSUInteger)section
{
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //Since it's always the same could be done elsewhere once for all.

    //Note I didn't check completely if the case were good, and I didn't add the background color logic, but it should be done here too.
    switch (style)
    {
        case RNCollectionCellStyleColumnTitle:
        {
            self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3);
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
        }
            break;
        case RNCollectionCellStyleColumnValue:
        {
            self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
        }
            break;
        case RNCollectionCellStyleRowTitle:
        {
            self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
        }
            break;
        case RNCollectionCellStyleUpperLeftCorner:
        {
            self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    self.textLabel.text = title;

}

-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
}
```

In `RNCollection`:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RNCollectionCell *contentCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Here check what style you need to do
    //Also, you seems to always do dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], you just use the "if test values".
    [contentCell titleIt:dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
                forStyle:RNCollectionCellStyleColumnTitle
              forSection:[indexPath section]];

    return contentCell;
}
```

As said, I didn't check if all the cases were correct according to your needs.
But, you don't "prevent reuse of cell", it's optimized.
You need to "reset" values before reused or when you set the values. In theory the thing done in `prepareForReuse` should be enough and you shouldn't have to "reset" the layer effect in the `switch`, but I honestly didn't check it.